# Oscilloscope voltage not matching function generator

Tags: power-electronics, oscilloscope, function-generator

What are the reasons why my oscilloscope shows a different voltage from my function generator?

I have set the Vpp of the function generator to be 10V, but I set the probe to 10x and on the device, it is set to 1x, for this setting I get 20.80V output.

When I set the device to 2x, I get 41.6V and at 10x I get 208V. I am new to using both devices and I don't know why I can't accurately get the voltage value from the function generator.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Most function generators will display the voltage output value that would be seen when running into a load terminator of the same impedance as the function generator. You are running the output (presumably a 50 ohm or 600 ohm output) into an open circuit (the o-scope) hence you see approximately twice the value that is displayed on the function generator. See this extract from Keysight Technologies: -

[image]