# Why is the scope showing half the value of the function generator?

Tags: voltage, oscilloscope, voltage-divider, load, function-generator

This is a follow up on this question: [Oscilloscope voltage not matching function generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504916/oscilloscope-voltage-not-matching-function-generator/504922#504922?newreg=6006ec6f5a4f493daf7cae2849e8e86c)

When the function generator is set to 50 Ω (R<sub>int</sub>), it automatically assumes that the external load R<sub>out</sub> (scope for example) is a 50 Ω load. As a result it puts out double the set voltage (40 mV for example, if you want to have 20 mV on the output).

The voltage division between two 50 Ω loads leads to:
V<sub>ext</sub> = V<sub>int</sub>·(R<sub>ext</sub>/(R<sub>int</sub>·R<sub>ext</sub>)) =
40·(50/50 + 50) = 20mV.

So on the scope you will see the exact setting of the function generator, but when the external load R<sub>out</sub> = 1 MΩ, the voltage division yields:
V<sub>ext</sub> = 40·(1 MΩ/1 MΩ + 50 Ω) = 40 mV.

Thus you will see double the set voltage on the scope. This makes sense.

Now my question:
When the function generator is set to HiZ (R<sub>int</sub>), and the scope is on 50 Ω, the voltage set is half of what you want (10 mV if the set voltage is 20 mV). Why is the reason for this?

Comment: When you set the function generator to HiZ, it does not adjust the output impedance. It is still 50ohm. But in this case, the voltage source does not put out double the voltage, but the exact voltage that you specified. So, with a high impedance input the 50 ohm output impedance is negliable, and you will see the set voltage. If you then put a 50 ohm input across the ouput, the voltage will be halved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the function generator is set to HiZ(R_int), and the scope is on 50ohm, the voltage set is half of what you want (10mV if the set voltage is 20mV). Why is the reason for this?

The function generator is driving the output with half the voltage that would be needed to get full output with a 50Ω load.

**The output impedance of the function generator  is still 50Ω when you set HiZ *load*- it's only the amplitude that changes!**

Remember that HiZ is used to describe the *load*. Nothing physically changes on the function generator side. HiZ on the generator basically means "cut the amplitude in half". That's all it does, really.

Comment: Technically it doesn't even modify the amplitude. It simply changes the *displayed value* on its display. In fact changing the HiZ/50ohm setting on the sig-gen won't change the output at all.

Comment: It definitely changes *something*, because the function generator I use at work outputs glitches when you turn the outputs on or off when in 50 Ω output mode (at least in pulse mode, the one I use most often), but works perfectly when in hi-Z output mode.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine That behavior is entirely arbitrary. Some generators change the output amplitude, some change the displayed amplitude. I've seen both.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Well, that's news to me. Every sig gen I used that had the option HiZ vs. 50 ohm simply changed the displayed value (Agilent/Keysight and BKprecision are the ones I used that i remember having that option). I gave it for granted it was a standard approach. Today I learned something! :-)

Comment: @Hearth see my other comment to Kuba.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine In case you're wondering, the unit in question is a Siglent SDG6032X (rebranded as a Teledyne Test Tools T3AFG350).

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine The HiZ/50ohm switch was on some analog generators as well, surprisingly enough.